# Simple Noun/Adjective Confusion

Tags: nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech

> **Honesty is the best policy**

In this sentence, it is clear that **Honesty** is the noun. But should **policy** also a noun?
I'm not good at grammar so I'm sorry if the question sounds dumb.

Comment: What do you mean with _the noun_? There can be tens or hundreds of nouns in a sentence, why would it be a problem to have more than one? Maybe you mix up _noun_ and _subject_?

Comment: Yes, policy is a noun there."Best" is the adjective in the sentence and qualifies (like adjectives do) the noun "policy".

Comment: It was just a question from a test. I was just confused.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubts @Userabc